# AngularJS HTML editor to leave all tags

Tags: html, angularjs, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a WYSIWYG HTML Editor plugin to create a full HTML document with, hence it shouldn't strip any HTML tag e.g

```
<html> <head> <body>
```

- AngularJS v1.5.7.
- ngSanitize is being used through the app.

The app currently uses summernote v0.8.1 and angular-summernote v0.8.1.
I've tried a bunch of other editors TextAngular etc. but they all strip the above-mentioned HTML tags out.

Comment: You can try **CKEditor** 4. Unlike other WYSIWYG editors it has a complex config settings, one of which allows you to edit a full HTML file with [config.fullPage](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-fullPage). To make it work with AngularJS, use [`angular-ckeditor`](https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor)

Comment: Thanks @AlekseySolovey I'll give that a go.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey that's done the job perfectly thanks again! The only issue I had with it was that the npm & bower install failed. I resorted to manually downloading the scripts.